# 4-Tuple Sequence To Map of Maps of Maps

Tags: scala

I need a more concise way to transform a sequence of tuples into a map of maps of maps... 
As a signature I get in case of `Tuple4`:

```
def tuple4Seq2MapOfMaps[A,B,C,D](seq: Seq[(A,B,C,D)]): Map[A,Map[B,Map[C,D]]]
```

The following code shows my recent *ugly* code, I stucked with (type `A` to `D` arbitrary):

```
type A = Int
type B = Double
type C = String
type D = Boolean
val tupleSeq = Seq[(A,B,C,D)](
  (1,1.0D,"a",true),
  (1,1.0D,"b",true),
  (1,1.0D,"c",false)
)
val x = tupleSeq.groupBy{ _._1 }.map{ case (k,s) => (k,s.map{ x => (x._2,x._3,x._4) }) }
val y = x.map{ case (k,s) => (k,s.groupBy{_._1}.map{ case (k,s) => (k,s.map{ x => (x._2,x._3) }) }) }
val z = y.map{ case (k1,m) => (k1,m.map{ case (k2,s1) => (k2,s1.groupBy{_._1}.map{ case (k3,s2) => (k3,s2.map{ _._2 }.head) }) }) }

val m = z(1)(1.0D)
println(m("b"))
```

Note the use of `head` at `val z`.

It would be nice to have a more concise way for only `Tuple4`, but furthermore interesting how to generalize this to `TupleN` (N >= 2).

Is there a nice approach in someones mind out there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best I can come up with is,

```
tupleSeq.groupBy(_._1).
  mapValues(_.groupBy(_._2).
    mapValues(_.groupBy(_._3).
      mapValues{ case Seq(p) => p._4 }))
```

Generalizing to tuples of higher arity is quite straightfoward ... just add additional nested applications of mapValues(_groupBy(_._n). ... and adjust the final pattern match accordingly.

Fully generalizing this as a function over tuples of arbitrary arity would be possible using HLists, but that would most likely be a far more heavyweight solution than is needed here. I'll leave this line of attack as an exercise for the questioner (or other commenters ;-).

Comment: As a supplemental: One should be aware of the fact that `mapValues` returns a view. See Rex Kerr´s nice answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433578/subsetof-versus-forall-contains

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest implicits on the tuples:

```
implicit def Tup3Cut[A,B,C](tup: (A,B,C)) = new {
  def decapitate = (tup._2,tup._3)
}
implicit def Tup4Cut[A,B,C,D](tup: (A,B,C,D)) = new {
  def decapitate = (tup._2,tup._3,tup._4)
}

val tupleSeq = Seq((1,1d,"a",true),(1,1d,"b",true),(1,1d,"c",false),(1,2d,"c",true))

tupleSeq.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(
  _.map(_.decapitate).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_.decapitate).toMap)
)
```