# subsetOf versus forall contains

Tags: scala

Consider I have:

```
case class X(...)
val xs: Seq[X] = ... // some method result
val ys: Seq[X] = ... // some other method result
```

While the following holds:

```
xs.distinct.sameElements(xs) // true
ys.distinct.sameElements(ys) // true
```

I am facing:

```
xs forall(ys contains _)    // true
xs.toSet subsetOf ys.toSet  // false
```

Why? I mean, it´s clear that making a `Set` out of a `Seq` chooses random elements in case of duplicates, but there are no duplicates because of "`(...).distinct.sameElements(...)`".

I certainly need a deeper understanding of the kind of equality check...

**EDIT:**

After a long search, I found the problem and condensed it to the following:

My elements are not the same, however I must take a closer look why `distinct.sameElements` isn´t complaining. But meanwhile a new question arose:

Consider this:

```
val rnd = scala.util.Random
def int2Label(i: Int) = "[%4s]".format(Seq.fill(rnd.nextInt(4))(i).mkString)
val s = Seq(1,2,3,4)

// as expected :
val m1: Map[Int,String] = s.map(i => (i,int2Label(i))).toMap
println(m1) // Map(5 -> [ 555], 1 -> [    ], 2 -> [  22], 3 -> [    ])
println(m1) // Map(5 -> [ 555], 1 -> [    ], 2 -> [  22], 3 -> [    ])

// but accessing m2 several times yields different results. Why?
val m2: Map[Int,String] = s.map(i => (i,i)).toMap.mapValues { int2Label(_) }
println(m2) // Map(5 -> [   5], 1 -> [  11], 2 -> [  22], 3 -> [ 333])
println(m2) // Map(5 -> [  55], 1 -> [  11], 2 -> [    ], 3 -> [    ])
```

So my elements in my first to sequences aren´t the same because they depend on a `m2`-construct and so each time a accessing them they are different.

My new question is, why does `m2` behave like a function in contrast to `m1` although both are immutable maps. That isn´t intuitively for me.

Comment: Duplicate and order of elements should not event matter in the last two statements. There's gotta be more to it than what you posted. What's the data?

Comment: The data `xs` and `ys` are two sequences, as said, of a composed type: `case class Edge(to: NodeID, label: Seq[(ActivityID,ActivityAssignment)] = Seq(), labelPrefix: String = "")`. Composed because of `NodeID`,`ActivityID`.`ActivityAssignment` which are also immutable case classes. The current sequences are too long to post here.

Comment: Can I suggest that you use ScalaCheck to find the shortest sequence verifying your property and post the results if it's small enough?

Comment: I guess try `if (! xs.toSet.subsetOf(ys.toSet)) println(xs.toSet -- ys)` and see what elements of *xs.toSet* are not in *ys.toSet*...

Comment: Thanks for all your advices and hints. But recently my question changed, see edit.

Comment: Your edit should be a new question as it is totally unrelated to the first, original part (or so I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common reasons for problems in this area--testing set equality and the like--are

1. `hashCode` does not agree with `equals`
2. Your values are not stable (so previous `hashCode` does not agree with current `equals`)

The reason is that this matters is that `distinct` and `toSet` use hash codes to build sets, whereas `contains` simply runs over the collection with an `exists`:

```
xs forall(ys contains _) == xs forall (x => ys exists (y => x==y) )
```

This is made more complicated by the fact that many sets don't start using hash codes until they're larger than some minimal size (usually 4), so you don't always notice this with testing.  But let's prove it to ourselves:

```
class Liar(s: String) {
  override def equals(o: Any) = o match {
    case l: Liar => s == l.s
    case _ => _
  }
  // No hashCode override!
}
val strings = List("Many","song","lyrics","go","na","na","na","na")
val lies = strings.map(s => new Liar(s))
val truly_distinct = lies.take(5)
lies.length          // 8
lies.distinct.length // 8!
lies.toSet.size      // 8!
lies forall( truly_distinct contains _ )   // True, because it's true
lies.toSet subsetOf truly_distinct.toSet   // False--not even the same size!
```

Okay, so now we know that for most of these operations, matching up `hashCode` and `equals` is a Good Thing.

Warning: in Java, mismatches happens frequently even with primitives:

```
new java.lang.Float(1.0) == new java.lang.Integer(1)                       // True
(new java.lang.Float(1.0)).hashCode == (new java.lang.Integer(1)).hashCode // Uh-oh
```

but Scala now at least catches that (hopefully every time):

```
(new java.lang.Float(1.0)).## == (new java.lang.Integer(1)).##   // Whew
```

Case classes also do this properly, so we're left with three possibilities

1. You overrode `equals` but not `hashCode` to match
2. Your values are not stable
3. There is a bug and Java wrapped primitive hashCode mismatch is coming back to bite you

The first one is easy enough.

The second one seems to be your problem, and it arises from the fact that `mapValues` actually creates a *view* of the original collection, not a new collection.  (`filterKeys` does this also.)  Personally, I think this is a questionable choice of design, since normally when you have a view and you want to make a single concrete instance of it, you `.force` it.  But default maps don't have a `.force` because they don't realize that they might be views.  So you have to resort to things like

```
myMap.map{ case (k,v) => (k, /* something that produces a new v */) }
myMap.mapValues(v => /* something that produces a new v */).view.force
Map() ++ myMap.mapValues(v => /* something that produces a new v */)
```

This is really important if you're doing things like file IO to map your values (e.g. if your values are filenames and you're mapping to their contents) and you don't want to read the file over and over again.

But your case--where you're assigning random values--is another where it is important to pick a single copy, not recreate the values over and over.